# How to dump all string values in an ArrayList C#

Tags: c#, arraylist, smtp

I'm trying to code an email button into a program I use at the school where I work (Essentially, the program generates random passwords for a class I input, it then sets those passwords for that session, and changes them after the session finishes). The email button is so it sends the usernames and passwords to the teachers without me having to manually type it out.

I've got to the point where I can send the email via an SMTP relay, and I receive it. I've formatted the subject line which I'm happy with, I'm just stuck on the body now. Essentially, I have an ArrayList which holds each line as a value. I'm looking for a way to dump each value in the ArrayList to a new line in the body. So far I have this:

```
mailMsg.Body = ("Hi," + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Below are the usernames and passwords for the Controlled Assessment." + Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine + "Usernames      Firstname   Surname       Passwords" + Environment.NewLine + "-----------------------------------------------------" + Environment.NewLine + );

My ArrayList is called SW, and I've parsed this into an Array too called aSW, using: String[] aSW = (String[]) SW.ToArray(typeof(string));
```

Can anyone give me pointers on how to do this? I apologise if more info is needed, only been coding in C# for about 3 weeks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `LINQ`

```
var arr = SW.OfType<string>().ToArray();
```

To concatenate all values with newline you can use `string.Join`

```
string.Join(Environment.NewLine, arr);
```

Comment: How would I put that into the body of the SMTP email?

Comment: @morjit you can use `string.Join` with `Environment.NewLine` but if this is an HTML email then it won't work. you need to use `<br>` instead.

Comment: Thanks Selman! That worked absolutely perfectly, thanks so much!

Comment: @morjit if the answer was useful for you please mark it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

U can declare a stringbuilder and append each item in the arraylist

and after that assign body = sb.tostring()